# Running Django on Google Colab

Tags: python, django, google-colaboratory

I was trying to run the Django on Colab, by following the instruction [here](https://medium.com/@arsindoliya/running-django-on-google-colab-ea9392cdee86), however, after the  `!python manage.py runserver` step, I tried to

> access the server using Google Colab link you printed by running the
> eval_js method earlier.

there is a error msg:

> This page isn’t working0yztv6fmakbj-496ff2e9c6d22116-8000-colab.googleusercontent.com is currently unable to handle this request.
> HTTP ERROR 500

then I tried to access the link http://127.0.0.1:8000/,

and it appears error msg as follows

> This page isn’t working127.0.0.1 didn’t send any data.

May I ask how to fix this? If this is not the way to run Django in Colab, what should I do?
and every time I run `!python manage.py runserver`, it keeps executing the

```
Performing system checks...
```

Is that normal?

Answer (score 4):

I can run it smoothly,this is my notebook https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1XcxOu_9w9Rs_m9bT3ueqeQmSctGvPjPB?usp=sharing, maybe you forgot to save the settings.py after changing ALLOWED_HOSTS, or maybe you didn't connect to the colab backend because colab disconnected the session after a few hours

sorry my english is not good

Comment: Generally, giving links is not a good idea because they can die after time passes. It would be better to give a quick summary and/or code snippet in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Everything is fine with your code but do not access the link http://127.0.0.1:8000/. Instead:

1. Open (double-click) the settings.py in the Files section (portfolio/portfolio/settings.py) and edit the following (it will be saved automatically):    `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['colab.research.google.com']`
2. I think it is optional but I would add and run `!python manage.py migrate` before running the server `!python manage.py runserver 8000`
3. Click on the link that was printed by eval_js (`print(eval_js("google.colab.kernel.proxyPort(8000)"))`)

Answer (score -1):

I got lost in the same place, but when I checked it more carefully, I found that the link generated on the way was the Django url. The localhost address at the end is irrelevant.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).